# How to pull entry data from a data extension into a journey builder fired email?

Tags: ampscript, journeybuilder, dataextensions

Hi Marketing cloud community,

I'm having trouble pulling in data from a data extension that triggers a journey into an email that fires from that journey.

Our journey is set up like this:

[image]

I am attempting to pull, for example, Region__c like this:

`var @jbRegion
set @jbRegion = AttributeValue("Region__c")`

Am I trying to access the data extension data incorrectly, or is something not set up correctly with our Journey?

Thank you,

Emil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to your entry data attributes (in your screenshot).

```
var @jbRegion
set @jbRegion = AttributeValue("Contact:Account:Region__c")
```